# Android Development Basic

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am not getting it that what is wrong in this piece of code.
Please tell me somebody[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JICBp.png)

I am learning this trough the android development path from the android studio platform and i
exactly did the same thing that they taught. But i am getting error.
I am expecting a reasonable explanation and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please read [ask], including the section about including code as text and not an image.

Answer (score 0):

These are part of Jetpack Library. So you will have to import them in your current class. Head your cursor over the red part and you will see option to add import. Alternatively, press **ALT + ENTER** on Windows or **CMD + ENTER** on Mac. You will see an option to add the import. Once you have added it you can verify in the imports section at top of your `MainActivity`.

Following imports should be added to your class.

1. `import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp`
2. `import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement`
3. `import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign`

[image: Import Option]